# Selecting dates next to each other in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Been trying to figure this out for a while now.

I am looking to select rows from a database table in MySQL where the two dates are next to each other.

e.g. 2011-07-20 is next to 2011-07-21.

Many Thanks

Neil

Comment: Are you wanting to search for a given date, and also find the next date, or do you want to want to return all row pairs that contain sequential dates?  Please can you give a clearer example of what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can `JOIN` using `ADDDATE()`:

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.id
FROM myTable AS T1
INNER JOIN myTable AS T2
    ON T1.DATE = ADDDATE(T2.DATE, -1)
WHERE T1.id < T2.id;
```

The `WHERE` is to verify that T1 and T2 don't contain duplicates.

Comment: What's with the two tables in here?

Comment: Thank you for fixing it, ypercube.

Comment: I would write it as `ON T1.DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY = T2.DATE` but you get my +1

Comment: I need to determine two dates that exist in the same column.

I tried writing:

SELECT DISTINCT(date_verified) FROM tbl_2for1er_user_attractions WHERE date_verified BETWEEN date_verified AND DATE_ADD(date_verified, INTERVAL 1 day) AND user_id = 2 

but I get 2011-07-20 saying it is next to 2011-07-22.

Maybe I am missing something!

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, this checks the same column on different rows in the same table. It's called a self join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2011-07-20' AND DATE_ADD('2011-07-20', INTERVAL 1 day)
```

**Manual:** 
[between operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)
[date_add function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)